# Is it possible to change the font in the SQL edit window in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

It would be nice if there was a right-mouse-click menu on the edit panel to change the font size, but there isn't.

Is there a system setting somewhere else that lets me increase the default font size?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Office Button > Access Options > Object Designers > Query design > Query design font

Comment: There's something wonky there, as it took me three tries before I got the font size change to stick.

Comment: Worked for me first time but IIRC I immediately (and instinctively) closed then re-opened the .accdb.

Comment: I only had to close and re-open my query window after changing this, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note, be sure to restart Access to allow the updates to take effect.

Comment: No need to restart. Just close any open query tabs, and re-open them. The effect will take place