# How to change the font size in the SQL Edit window of Access 16 (Office 365)?

Tags: ms-access, office365, ms-office

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599064/is-it-possible-to-change-the-font-in-the-sql-edit-window-in-access-2007), this is how you change the font size in Access 2007:

> Office Button > Access Options > Object Designers > Query design >
>   Query design font

In Access 16.0 (part of the Office 365 suite) I cannot find this. First off, I don't know what the *Office Button* is. Is that something that exists in Office 16.x? Here's what I see:

[image]

Secondarily, I looked all over trying to find *Access Options* or *Object Designers* or *Query Design*, and I'm not finding much of anything related to font size. There is a *Query Design* view, which looks like this:

[image]

...but I can't find anything related to font size on the SQL editor view.

Comment: File tab>>Options>>Object Designers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File tab>>Options>>Object Designers

Comment: Works great. Not sure why MS Access wants to make the world go blind with a default 8-pt font. Thank you Sorceri.

Comment: While you are at it, change the font to `Consolas`.

Comment: The font changes are applied after Access is restarted - at least in the Office 365 that I currently use